# Opening source code instead of decompiled class in eclipse 3.5 and jd-eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse

I have set up eclipse (Eclipse 3.5) to associate the java run time jars with the source code.
I have accomplished this by associating my JDK rt.jar with the source code that ships with jdk (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\src.zip).

I also happen to have jd-eclipse decompiler plugin setup.

When I click on say a HashMap class, it opens up the decompiled HashMap class; where as I wanted to see the source code (from the JDK src.zip file).
Is it possible to tell eclipse to:

1. Open the associated source code for a library class if available.
2. If the source code is not available; then and only then decompile the class?

System Info:
Eclipse 3.5

jd-eclipse 0.1.3

OS: windows 7, 64 bit Enterprise edition

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [blog post](http://mchr3k-coding.blogspot.de/2012/07/realignment-for-jd-eclipse.html), the author describes two problems the *jd-eclipse* plugin has:

> 1. The generated source code doesn’t line up with the debug line numbers because the generated code can’t include the original comments.
> 2. If you choose to associate the “*.class” file type within Eclipse with the “Class File Editor” then you always get decompiled output even if you have real source attached.

I guess *2.* is the problem you are facing and it appears that jd-eclipse is not capable of what you need.

It looks like the [Mchr3k - JDEclipse-Realign](http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/) might help you here. (I am not sure if it is available for your eclipse version though. Time to get an updated Eclipse perhaps...)

Comment: I use JDEclipse-Realign, and when I attempt to visit JDK classes, I get the source from the associated src.zip, instead of the decompiled version.  However, I can force it to give me the decompiled version if I change the default of the "Open Class With ..." menu item.